# smtlib not send email to email address from column list of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, oracle, smt-lib

Dears

I have a Code Connect to Oracle DB, get query as Daraframe and send email to receiver that  exist in a column

As I Test When I set test_reciver argument to an email address test_reciver Email received
but when I set (email Receiver) to the column of data frame, Email not received

```
#send mail function
def send_email(subject,to,cc,body):
    sender_email = 'test@test.com'
    receivers = to
    host = "bulkmail.test.com"
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host)
    msg = MIMEText(body)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['to'] = to
    msg['cc'] = cc
    server.sendmail(sender_email,to,msg.as_string())
    server.quit()


query = "select * from sometable"
test_reciver = "myemail@test.com"

con = cx_Oracle.connect(user_db,password_db,dsn_tns,encoding="UTF-8", nencoding="UTF-8")
cc = 'emailcctest@test.com'
df = pd.read_sql_query(query,con, index_col=None).head(1)
df = df.reset_index()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['EMAIL'])
    subject = 'please clarify your Workgroup in SDM '
    to = row['EMAIL']
    body = 'sample body'
    send_email(subject, to, cc, body)

con.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

it is solved by sending email as an object with send_message instead of sendmail for smtplib

```
#send mail function
def send_email(subject,to,cc,body):
    host = "bulkmail.test.com"
    server = smtplib.SMTP(host)
    msg = MIMEText(body)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = 'test@test.com'
    msg['to'] = to
    msg['cc'] = email_cc
    serve.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution.  In general, I'd recommend you upgrade cx_Oracle - see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).

Comment: oracledb is not support my oracle version

Comment: python-oracledb connects to the same DB versions that cx_Oracle 8 supports.  You can use Instant Client with python-oracledb to connect to Oracle DB 9.2 or later.